# Vue assets: change the files path at compilation

Tags: vue.js, assets, vue-cli

I am trying to find a way to change the file location at compilation.

In my project, some assets files are defined in public/aclib/. However I would like to get them in /public *only in the compiled version* as that's what the code uses.

Of course, I could just put those files directly in public/ in the project, but I'd like them to be in a subfolder for the project clarity.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Search for **copy-webpack-plugin**

For example, in **vue.config.js** add property:

```
configureWebpack: {
   new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "public/aclib", to: "public" }
      ],
   }),
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a mistake in my description, the destination isn't "/publc" but the root built folder (as "dist" when doing a production build).

For info, I've had it working using this property instead:

const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
       ...
        plugins: [
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: "./public/aclib", to: "./" },
                ],
            }),
        ],
    },
...
}